# {close} CAN't use the Object. Reason: haven't had a place to store the player

Tags: java, blackjack

I do the first part but the playeri can't use in the second part
because I forget to create an array to store it:

```
Player[] player = new Player[11];//solution add a array to store the player

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
boolean finishplayeri = false;
Player playeri = new  Player("player"+i); //if you don't create a array to store your player
player[i] = playeri;
}
```

second part:

```
for(int i=1;i<=noofplayer;i++) { 
player[i].addCard(theDeck.NextCard());  // in here your player[i] will be error
player[i].addCard(theDeck.NextCard());          
player[i].printHand(false);
}
```

Question: CAN't use the Object.
Reason: haven't had a place to store your player.
method: create an array to store my player.

Comment: The eclipse error code is : playeri cannot be resolved

Comment: You need to read about variable scopes.  You can't use variables outside of the scope in which they are declared.

Comment: Create a list or array to hold all the `Player` objects.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I try it now, thx for the advice.

Comment: Hi. Have a look at [Help: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit the question just to the code producing the same result. Can you make a testing code where just the instanciating of the Players is done, producing same result?

Comment: @BranislavKollár thx, I am a student come to from Hong Kong. My English level no very good. thx for the advice, I will try to make my question be shorter!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your Players in container to handle it. You don`t store your players anywhere.

Comment: You can use this link for information about collections in Java. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_collections.htm

Comment: you say that I need to create an array to carry my player, `int[] player = new int[10];` like that? and i put my player into the array-player?

Comment: int is not working , i try `Player[] player = new Player[10];` it is  like work now.

Comment: Of course your array must have type Player. I advice you to use List. It will like look List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(); and after that you can add players like: players.add(new Player("")); and get it by index like players.get(<your index>); or use for in forEach style.